# jquery css change outline of input to none

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, jquery-selectors

Ok. I know some of you are reading this and already asking why I'm so stupid and why I dont do this with simple CSS.

```
input:focus { outline:none; }
```

Simple... for some reason wordpress is not allowing this change to happen - so I am reverting to jquery to do the dirty work.

Problem is for me.. I can't get it to work either....

http://jsfiddle.net/h5KEm/ is the link to the following code on jsfiddle:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="optin" name="optin"><br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="go">
</form>​

$('input[name=optin]').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline', none');    
});​
```

Comment: To todo CSS you might just need to be more specific. If not you can try input:focus { outline:none!important; }

Comment: But see, even that 'css' won't work in wordpress for some reason. I don't know why it's acting up, but it's definitely being odd.

Comment: you can try `input { outline: none; }` and not the the `:focus` selector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a typo (a missing quote) :

```
$('#optin').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline', 'none');    
});​
```

Note that I also replaced `'input[name=optin]'` by `'#optin'` because this is cleaner and faster to use the id when you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change from the click event to the focus event

```
$('input[name=optin]').focus(function() {
    $(this).css('outline', 'none');    
});
```